# database structure - each category has custom fields

Tags: mysql, database

I am designing a app and need help in my database structure. I have several categories and based on the selected category I have custom fields that the user gets. for example

category : hotels

custom fields: 1) type of hotel 
               2) capacity from .... to ...
               3) etc

other category has another custom fields

can you suggest how you would structure the db

thank you
Dany

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

categories:
id, name, etc...

custom_fields:
id, category_id, field_label, field_type, maybe some other stuff

If the custom fields are things that a user fills in and you save, you will need another table.
custom_fields_values:
id, user_id, custom_field_id, value

Comment: thank you for info, the problem is that each category will have a custom fields, so your suggestion will work only for the specific category

Comment: Oh I see. Misread the problem. I may have something else. Give me a few minutes

Comment: So "a few minutes" apparently means an hour. Is my new answer better for you?